# How do I remove devices for running Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried creating a new flutter project in Visual Studio Code, but for whatever reason it now has a default device of Google Chrome every time I try to run it. I don't want to run Flutter in web environments whatsoever: is there any way I can disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following command to disable web completely.

```
flutter config --no-enable-web
```

Then restart your editor if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First, run your emulator from the AVD manager or connect your physical device while it's on debugging mode, if it's an android device, then choose the device you want to run from the flutter device selection option
[image]